# Vue CLI build and run index.html file without server

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-cli

I'm using the latest `vue-cli` [version 3.0](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli).

My current issue is that whenever I run `npm run build` the files generated in the `dist` folder can't be run without a server.

I would like to be able to just open the index.html file on the browser. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Because of how strict browsers are with reading local files (for security reasons) it's hopeless to do any local webdev-testing without spinning up a web server.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by manually changing the `url` of the referenced files.

It's a bit of a pain, but this was a solution without having to mess around with the build configuration.

What you need to do:

1. Open `index.html`
2. Find `href=/` and replace with `href=`
3. Find `src=/` and replace with `src=`

**NOTE: I was in need of this solution because I was creating a Phonegap app.**

Comment: How about asset files? Mine are stored in `/src/assets/img/...`, then in the `/dist/` folder, they're moved to `/dist/img/...`

Answer (score 39):

I ran into a similar issue and the following two changes helped me to make it work. Now I can just open index.html in Chrome as a file to **run my SPA from file system**.

1. In [`vue.config.js`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#vue-config-js), I did not have a `publicPath` configured, which resulted in the default `"/"`.
   I had to configure it to empty string like this so that it uses relative paths:

   ```
   module.exports = {
       publicPath: '',
   }
   ```

   <sup>PS: *Since Vue CLI 3.3 use `publicPath` instead of the now deprecated `baseURL`*</sup>
2. I was using the `history` mode of `vue-router`, which does not work
   on a local file system  to route the paths back to index.html. So I
   omitted the mode to go back to the default `hash` mode.

Comment: This should be `publicPath` now, as `baseUrl` is deprecated

Comment: This answer saved my day. Better solution than the marked answer.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the http-server module

```
npm install http-server -g
http-server dist/
```

normally the server starts at port 8080 so you can serve the build app on http://localhost:8080

Comment: I'm actually trying to use the generated files for a mobile app so I won't be able to run a server.

Comment: I assume that you are not developing the Vue app on the mobile device. So start the server on your development machine, put the mobile device in the same LAN and open the browser on the device on http://ip-of-dev:8080

Comment: I'm developing it using Phonegap. I've found another way around it, will post the answer soon. Thanks for looking into it. I appreciate it.