# Nuxt SPA without node server

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I head to create `Nuxt SPA` with routing and mb API in future like that:

1. Backend server (on `express` or smth else) listen and on request give entire SPA to client.
2. Now user can use everything on client side (include routing) with no more else requests to backend (mb API requests only)

It means that server should give some `.html` file with `js` and `css` files as `SPA` and it will work on client side.

I tried to run some commands like `nuxt build` and `nuxt generate`
It looks like they return a same result - `js` files couldn't be found

And `index.html` file doesn't work properly

After some researching I found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50809987/vue-cli-build-and-run-index-html-file-without-server)

But now I got this: [image]

It can't open the fourth `js` file in another `js` file. Path isn't right!
[image]

Every time I tried to run it as a static `html` file and from localhost (and also with using [Live Server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer))

I think I did a lot of crutches and there should be another built-in function or feature that allows us to do what I want

I wrote a lot - if I made a mistake or you didn't get smth - please, ask! I need any help

Comment: It generates an folder called `dist` and you need to grab everything inside and upload it to your webserver

Comment: @Ifaruki can I run it locally?

Comment: yea, but you need an local server and not the filesystem. a good way is to install XAMPP and run an server with it

Comment: @Dominux, you can just use `Web Server for Chrome` to localhost the `dist` folder with 1-2clicks, if for just client-side

Answer (score 0):

To test your locally built application, you need to serve all files within the generated `/dist` folder. You can setup very easily a local web server using Express/Node.js as you already have Node.js installed when running Nuxt. Create a new folder and install `express` via `npm` (run `npm install express`).

Then, copy everything from `/dist` into `/public` and create a file `server.js`:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.listen(3000);
```

Run the web server with `node server.js` and you can access your generated files on `http://localhost:3000`.

Comment: As I said before, I've already tried running with using localhost server, but it doesn't work