# GET http://localhost/resources/js/app.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm using laravel and vue , but when i try to load the page the data in home.vue doesnt apper is welcome.blade.php and this error appear in the console:
`GET http://localhost/resources/js/app.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

my webpack file is:

```
 mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
.vue()
.sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

and my welcome.blade.php is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <router-view></router-view>
    <script src="/resources/js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

my app.js path is:
/resources/js/app.js

Answer (score 0):

Path to yor JS script file is wrong and the browser can't find it.
Use `mix` helper to link to your compiled files. [ also you're missing your styles file. ]
You can't use `<router-view/>` in your blade file rather you need an element with `id="app"` so that vue can mount.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}" />
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: problem resolved no longer error ,but the data in home.vue still doesnt apper in welcome.blade.php

Answer (score 0):

change assets path to :

```sh
<script src="resources/js/app.js"></script>
```

or
setup webpack build config

```sh
assetsPublicPath: './'
```

or
vue.config.js:

```sh
module.exports = {
    publicPath: '',
}
```

There is a reloated problem.

[Vue CLI build and run index.html file without server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50809987/vue-cli-build-and-run-index-html-file-without-server)